# At what point do web browsers unblock interactive events exactly?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, dom-events, html-rendering

The `readystatechange` event has a state *named* “interactive”, which sounds like that the browser is *blocking interactive events* beforehand. Is that standardized somewhere? What are the details?

I mean, if the browser would not defer/postpone or block those events, then there would always be a race condition with Javascript attaching event handlers, unless Javascript is mixed with HTML (either with attributes like `onclick` or Javascript generates the whole element itself).

<sub>Example: A browser loading a huge page might already render parts of the DOM visible to the user (subject to changes, of course) without having even finished downloading the HTML. What if the user clicks something? Will that event be ignored, delivered now or executed later? I hope it will deliver later with the event object being generated and routed at the time of unblocking, not at the click time.—Ignoring is fine, too.</sub>

Comment: I think onclick events will just be triggered imeadiately no matter if the page has fully loaded or not. Unfortunately I cannot even find the specification for click (and other) events

Comment: Here are my findings: The [DOM Spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#events) defines how events are triggered, however it is completely agnostic of it's surrounding. The JavaScript Realm gets created when the browsing context gets created, so events can be processed even when the page is still loading according to the [DOM spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#creating-a-new-browsing-context). I could not find any section describing when and how microtask queues are processed during loading. So no answer is probably an answer too.

Comment: @JonasWilms I also fear that the browser does not block anything... And everything can perfectly be clicked/dragged/whatever in the middle of loading.—But than at least the `readyState` “interactive” is a big misnomer: the page is interactive from the very beginning then.

Answer (score 1):

> which sounds like that the browser is *blocking interactive events* beforehand

No it doesn't sound like that, *interactive* here only means we can interact with the Document safely: its markup has been completely parsed and its DOM is fully ready, it is now interactive.

No link whatsoever with UI-events, an User-Agent could implement that part of the specs without handling any UI-event (think headless browsers).

Before the [Document is even created](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#read-html), its [*browserContext*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#creating-a-new-browsing-context) will already have its [*agent*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#integration-with-the-javascript-agent-cluster-formalism) set, and its [event-loop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#definitions-3) running.
So even before the document is created, the event loop could receive UI-events, <sub>though I don't think there is anything outside of the Document where it could be dispatched from</sub>.

As to when these events will get dispatched, I think there is some interop issues here, but theoretically, the HTML parsing should be synchronous and these events should get dispatched asynchronously.
<sub>Not too sure about UI-events, but at least some network events like *load* were dispatched synchronously before the full parsing in Webkit browsers for years</sub>

Comment: "interactive here only means we can interact with the Document safely: its markup has been completely parsed and its DOM is fully ready, it is now interactive." -- Who is 'we'? And I don't see any relationship between the English word 'interactive' and the concept of 'completely parsed'. In reality the webpage is interactive beforehand: click events will be dispatched. And it is not 'unsafe' to handle them. "Only" the DOM is not done loading.

Comment: First definition here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interactive "we" is whatever script that web-authors or User-Agents control. And once again, there is just no relation between this concept ans UI events.

Comment: My point is: "its markup has been A and its DOM is B, it is now C." Are you defining C here, or using it to summarize A and B? -- Because I see no room here to use 'interactive' as C to clarify, or summarize. And to establish a new technical term here underlines what I think: it is a misnomer.

Comment: No it's not a misnomer, you are misreading it... Yes, there is a first state where the document doesn't exists, then there is an other where it is "loading", meaning that it hasn't ended all the parsing of the markup yet, and that if a script were to try interacting with it, it will not have the full DOM tree available yet, then a third state where it is "interactive" in that scripts can interact with it safely, the DOM tree is complete, but there are still some external resources being fetched and finally a fourth state "complete" where the loading a document algo is simply finished.

Comment: And I don't understand the second paragraph of the answer. Is there a verb missing?

Comment: I don't think so no, if you want verbose version that would be "There is no link whatsoever with UI-Events, an User-Agent could implement that part of the specs without handling any UI-event ( you can think of headless browsers for such a case )."

Comment: And is your answer saying 'events are unblocked from the very beginning' i.e. 'never blocked in the first place'? Or is "HTML parsing should be synchronous and these events should get dispatched asynchronously" saying that no event handlers (async) can come in the middle of HTML parsing (sync), because it is single-threaded?

Comment: What "event" are you talking about? The ones from the OS to the browser? These shouldn't be blocked no. The browser should queue them as soon as the event loop begins and this is before the Document is created as I said in my answer. If you mean javascript Events, then these should theoretically only be dispatched after the whole HTML has been parsed, since parsing the HTML is a synchronous operations and that these events should have been queued.

Comment: E.g. click events from already displayed HTML (as in the example of my question).

Comment: Yes but what "event"? You understand there are two completely different concepts called "event"? You clicking the mouse's button will trigger an electronic input that the computer will transmit to the Operating System. From there the OS will emit this event to the browser app. That event will be handled immediately by the browser, which will **queue a task** to dispatch a DOM Event on the DOM element where the pointer was. So the event handlers you'd have added from js should be notified of this event asynchronously, after the document is interactive. But the OS event is handled even before.

Comment: So you say that browsers delay the JS click event to a time after the `document.readyState` changes to `interactive`?

Comment: I say they theoretically should. I mean it's what is written in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

**Are events blocked in the beginning? No.** The page is as “interactive” as it could be even during main page load, so I do consider the `interactive` readyState a misnomer indeed. Events will be fired “as usual” and can pile up if the handler(s) take too much time, also as usual.

Network handling is probably done concurrent to Javascript execution<sup>1</sup>, but HTML parsing is not. The advancement in HTML parsing is almost like a task on the Javascript run queue: either HTML is parsed, or Javascript is executed and if Javascript does not yield, no further HTML will be parsed.

Priorities are handled differently in Chrome and Firefox: e.g. Chrome will consistently schedule event handling before further HTML parsing, while Firefox often (but not always) seems to parse buffered HTML before scheduling the next event handler.

And all this happens while `document.readyState` is on `loading`.—I observed this with the browser console and a hand-made server slowly dishing out simple HTML with inline script parts before entering a loop where it sends `<p>...` elements after a sleep, i.e. it never finished serving.

**Summary: `readyState === 'interactive'` is nothing more than “main page finished parsing.”**

<sub><sup>1</sup>additional restrictions apply as usual: e.g. immediate <script> execution before further parsing etc...</sub>